# PHP If this option is selected, do this

Tags: php, mysql

I have a very simple IF statement that worked for me a week ago, but mysteriously doesn't work for me now. I have a field when selected, creates an extra query.

The problem is, the doc is completely skipping over my if statement like it doesn't even exist

Here's the WHOLE CODE

```
<body id="bdy" onload="javascript:fg_hideform('fg_formContainer','fg_backgroundpopup');">
        <div class="container_22" id="container">
            <div id="rootDiv">
                <div style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"
                id="wrapper">
                    <div class="main">
                        <div id="mainMiddle" class="main-middle">
                            <div id="content" class="wide-content"
                            style="position: relative; width: 990px; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);

                            display: inline; margin-left:

                            15px;">
                                <span id="cntntMiddle_bannerTop"></span><!-- =search-bar | start -->
                                <div id="cntntMiddle_SearchBoxContainer"
                                style="margin-top: 20px; padding-left: 20px;">
                                    <form action="search.php" class="search-bar" method="GET">
                                        <h3>Search</h3>
                                        <fieldset>
                                            <div class="ctrlHolder inline">
                                                <input type="checkbox" name="r" id="r" value="y">
                                                Return Flight?
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="ctrlHolder

                                            inline">
                                                <input type="hidden" class="fnc-direction" id="curusd" name="Currency" value="USD"  /> </div>    <div id="trip-1" class="fnc-trip first">      <h6 ><span id="flight1">Departing Flight</span>  </h6>  <div

class="ctrlHolder"> <label for="from-1">  <span class="left">From</span> <span class="right">(City or Airport)</span> </label>  <?php
    $autocomplete1 = array();
    mysql_connect('localhost', '', ''); 
    mysql_select_db('');
    $sql = "SELECT distinct rout_from FROM search_v ORDER BY rout_from ASC";
    $r = mysql_query($sql);
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($r))
{
      $autocomplete1[] = $row['rout_from'];
    }
?><input id="newsearch1" name="departure_label">

</div>  <div class="ctrlHolder"><label for="from-1">  <span class="left">To</span> <span class="right">(City or Airport)</span> </label>  <?php
    $autocomplete = array();
    mysql_connect('localhost', '', ''); 
    mysql_select_db('');
    $sql = "SELECT distinct rout_to FROM search_v ORDER BY rout_to ASC";
    $r = mysql_query($sql);
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($r))
{
      $autocomplete[] = $row['rout_to'];
    }
?><input id="newsearch" name="arrival_label"> </div>  <div class="ctrlHolder"> <label for="leave-1">Depart</label>  

<input type="text" id="f" name="txtDate1"/> </div> <div class="ctrlHolder"> <label for="leave-2">Arrive</label>  

<input type="text" id="t" name="txtDate2"/></div>  </div>  </fieldset> <fieldset class="travelers">

<legend>Travelers
                                            </legend>
                                            <div class="ctrlHolder inline-select clearfix">
                                                <div class="field">
                                                    <label for="adults">
                                                        <br />
                                                        Passengers</label>
                                                    <select

                                                    name="ddlPAxADT" id="ddlPaxADT">
                                                        <option selected="selected"

                                                        value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option

                                                        value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option><option value="5">5</option>
                                                    </select>
                                                </div>
                                                <br>
                                            </div>
                                        </fieldset>
                                        <div class="submit-wrap

                                        clearfix">
                                            <button class="btn-reset" type="reset">
                                                Reset
                                            </button>
                                            <input

                                            name="submit" class="btn-search" type="submit" />
                                        </div>
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                                <div id="cntntMiddle_search-results" class="search-results">
                                    <span id="cntntMiddle_lblResults"> <h2>Search Results</h2> <h3>Showing <span id="cntntMiddle_ctl01_lblFlightFilter">all
                                            results</span></h3> 
        <?php
mysql_connect('localhost', '', ''); 
mysql_select_db(''); 

                                        $search = $_GET['search'];
                                        $sfrom = $_GET['departure_label'];
                                        $sto = $_GET['arrival_label'];
                                        $sfromda = $_GET['txtDate1'];
                                        $stoda = $_GET['txtDate2'];
                                        $padt = $_GET['ddlPaxADT'];
                                        $currency = $_GET['Currency'];
                                        $ret = $_GET['r'];
                                        if ($ret!='y') {
                                        $sql1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM search_v WHERE rout_to='$sfrom' AND rout_from='$sto' AND date_avialable='$stoda'") or die(mysql_error());
                                        $runrows1 = mysql_fetch_array($sql1);
                                        $flightid1 = $runrows1['flight_id'];
                                        $aseats1 = $runrows1['seats_avialable'];
                                        $todate1 = strftime("%b %d, %Y %l:%M %p" ,strtotime($runrows1['to_date']));
                                        $date1 = strftime("%b %d, %Y %l:%M %p" ,strtotime($runrows1['date_avialable']));
                                        $from1 = $runrows1['rout_from'];
                                        $to1 = $runrows1['rout_to'];
                                        $acost1 = $runrows1['adult_cost'];
                                        $ccost1 = $runrows1['child_cost'];
                                        $cur1 = $runrows1['currency'];
                                        $oth1 = $runrows1['other_cost'];
                                        $totalcost1= $acost1+$oth1;
                                        $pr1 = $flightid1+5;

                                        }
                                        //echo outconstruct
                                        $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM search_v WHERE currency='$currency' AND

                                        rout_to='$sto' AND rout_from='$sfrom' AND DATE_FORMAT(date_avialable,'%Y-%m-%d')

                                        between'".$sfromda."' and '".$stoda."' LIMIT 10") or die(mysql_error()) ;
                                        while ( $runrows = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
                                        {

                                        //get data
                                        $flightid = $runrows['flight_id'];
                                        $aseats = $runrows['seats_avialable'];
                                        $todate = strftime("%b %d, %Y %l:%M %p" ,strtotime($runrows['to_date']));
                                        $date = strftime("%b %d, %Y %l:%M %p" ,strtotime($runrows['date_avialable']));
                                        $from = $runrows['rout_from'];
                                        $to = $runrows['rout_to'];
                                        $acost = $runrows['adult_cost'];
                                        $ccost = $runrows['child_cost'];
                                        $cur = $runrows['currency'];
                                        $oth = $runrows['other_cost'];
                                        $totalcost= $acost+$oth;
                                        $pr = $flightid+5;
                                        echo "";
                                        ?>
<?PHP
include('popup/contactform-code.php');
?>
                                        <ul class="result-list clearfix">
                                            <li class="item clearfix">
                                                <span
                                                id="cntntMiddle_ctl01_rptmain_lblFromt_0">
                                                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                                        <thead>
                                                            <tr>
                                                                <th class="price">Price<?php echo $ret; ?></th>
                                                                <th>From</th>
                                                                <th>To</th>
                                                                <th>Depart</th>
                                                            </tr>
                                                        </thead>
                                                        <tfoot>
                                                            <tr>

                                                                <td colspan="6">
                                                                <div class="select-wrap">
                                                                    <p class="seats">
                                                                        <strong><?php echo $aseats; ?></strong><span>seats
                                                                            left</span><em>at this price</em>
                                                                    </p>                                                                <a href='javascript:fg_popup_form("fg_formContainer","fg_form_InnerContainer","fg_backgroundpopup");'
><img border='0' src='images/select_flight.png' width='121' height='34' /></a>
                                                                </div></td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                        </tfoot>
                                                        <tbody>
                                                            <tr>
                                                                <td class="price" rowspan="2"><a
                                                                style="font-weight: bold; cursor: pointer; text-decoration: none;"
                                                                herf="#" onclick='return ray.ajax("#");'><span
                                                                style="font-size: 24px; font-weight: bold;"><?php echo $totalcost; ?></span><span
                                                                style="font-size: 11px; margin-top: 2px; display: block; color: rgb(255, 255,

                                                                255); text-align: center; font-

                                                                weight: normal;">per
                                                                    person</span><span
                                                                style="font-size: 12px; margin-top: 2px; display: block; color: rgb(255, 255,

                                                                255); text-align: center; font-

                                                                weight: normal;">(with fees)</span></a></td>
                                                                <td><?php echo $from; ?></td>
                                                                <td><?php echo $to ?></td>
                                                                <td style="padding-right: 2px;"><?php echo $date; ?></td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                            <tr>
                                                                <td><?php echo $to1; ?></td>
                                                                <td><?php echo $from1 ?></td>
                                                                <td style="padding-right: 2px;"><?php echo $date1; ?></td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                        </tbody>
                                                    </table> </span><a
                                                id="cntntMiddle_ctl01_rptmain_lblResultDetails1_0" title="1"
                                                href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$cntntMiddle$ctl01$rptmain

                                                $ctl00$lblResultDetails1','')"
                                                style="color: Black;"></a><a class="close"
                                                href="#">Close</a>
                                                <div class="info clearfix">
                                                    <div class="info clearfix">
                                                        <h4>Departing Flight</h4>
                                                        <ul class="clearfix">
                                                            <li>
                                                                <h5><?php echo $from; ?> to <?php echo $to; ?> <?php echo $date; ?></h5>
                                                                <ul>
                                                                    <li>
                                                                        &nbsp;
                                                                    </li>
                                                                    <li>
                                                                        <strong>Flight #</strong> - <?php echo $flightid; ?>
                                                                    </li>
                                                                    <li>
                                                                        <strong>Departure Time – </strong>
                                                                        <?php echo $date; ?>
                                                                    </li>
                                                                </ul>
                                                            </li>
                                                        </ul>
                                                        <ul>
                                                            <li style="padding-top: 5px;">
                                                                <span
                                                                style="color: rgb(212, 22, 13); font-weight: bold; font-size: 11px; text-

                                                                decoration: none;"> Fare Breakdown</span>
                                                            </li>
                                                        </ul>
                                                        <table class="more">
                                                            <tbody>
                                                                <tr>
                                                                    <th>Passenger</th>
                                                                    <th>Fare</th>
                                                                    <th> Taxes and Fees</th>
                                                                    <th>Qty</th>
                                                                    <th>Total Cost</th>
                                                                </tr>
                                                            </tbody>
                                                            <tbody>
                                                                <tr>
                                                                    <td>Adult</td>
                                                                    <td
                                                                    style="color: rgb(100, 100, 100); font-size: 11px; font-weight: bold;"><?php

                                                                    echo $acost; ?></td>
                                                                    <td><?php echo $oth; ?></td>
                                                                    <td id="paxAdtTd">1</td>
                                                                    <td><?php echo $acost; ?></td>
                                                                </tr>
                                                                <tr>
                                                                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                                                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                                                    <td>Cost of Sale(<?php echo $cur; ?>)</td>
                                                                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                                                    <td
                                                                    style="color: rgb(100, 100, 100); font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold;"><?php

                                                                    echo $totalcost; ?></td>
                                                                </tr>
                                                            </tbody>
                                                        </table>
                                                        <br />
                                                        <span style="font-weight: bold; padding-top: 10px;"> *Additional airline fees for baggage may apply</span>
                                                        <div class="select-wrap">
                                                            <p class="seats">
                                                                <strong><?php echo $aseats; ?></strong><span>seats
                                                                    left</span><em>at this price</em>
                                                            </p>
                                                            <button class="btn-select" type="button" id="start">
                                                                Select
                                                                Flight
                                                            </button>
                                                        </div>
                                            </li>
                                        </ul> </ul>
                                        </ul>
                                         <?php ;}?>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

Comment: You have a value called `$ret`.  Does it come from a form input?  Did you previously [have `register_globals` turned on](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php) and now it has been disabled?  `var_dump($_POST);`  For example, if you just upgraded to PHP5.4,  register_globals is totally gone.

Comment: Could you post the code where you assign to $ret? It's hard to see what that value is without your code. Also, I would probably use mysql_fetch_assoc() instead of mysql_fetch_array() in this instance.

Comment: What have you tried to solve your problem? I would suggest doing `var_dump($ret)` before your if statement to see where you're at. You should also look into PDO instead of the deprecated mysql_*

Comment: provided code is fine ... where $ret is getting filled? Surely, your `if ($ret!='y')` is returning false and so it's getting skipped. That is, $ret is not equal to 'y'

Comment: Did you checked, that $ret is 'Y' instead of 'y'. Try printing `$ret` and see what value does it have.

Comment: I just edited the question. $ret is getting filled in an input field. I used the GET variable to retrieve it. The problem isn't with $ret, so I assumed I got the IF wrong

Comment: I triple checked. This sort of thing has been happening all day. Code that I know to be right stop working. So I have to find alternatives to everything. I was kind of hoping there was an alternative to this

Comment: How do you know it's skipping over your "if"? In other words, what are you doing with the vars $pr1 and $totalcost1 later that makes you think your "if" statement isn't working?

Comment: How do you validate that, this if segment is not invoking at all? did you checked it?

Comment: Also, your sql query inside provided if segment ... shouldn't it be ... `$sql1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM search_v WHERE rout_to='$sto' AND rout_from='$sfrom' AND date_avialable='$stoda'") or die(mysql_error());`

Comment: @jrubins I'm trying to echo them out in a div IF the option 'r' is selected. If its not, it shouldn't display anything. But the thing is, it's not displaying anything. Even if it is selected.

Comment: Hmm, I think it would be helpful if you could edit your question to have ALL the code of this script so we could look at everything you're doing. It's possible there's some little mistake that's messing everything up.

Comment: I have absolutely no idea what's wrong today. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: @MarieeMcCullin, I think it's because of trailing newline character. So, before you actually do `if($ret != 'y')` just trim it `$ret = trim($ret)`. give it a try and let know if works.

Comment: LOL. I'm pretty sure it's my server. It went down last week (our providers got banned for spamming), so we had to duplicate all of our info on another server. Maybe the php I use isn't compatible with the new server?

Comment: I'd be surprised if that were the case. You're just using $_GET[] which should exist in all versions of PHP

Comment: I think you should create an empty file and delete everything except the form with the checkbox on it and the php that grabs "r" and echo's something depending on its value.

Comment: Who the hell is going to scan this huge code?? Only put the code that is needed. REMOVE IRRELEVANT CODE...

Comment: Read the comments before you write anything. I put the relevant code and no one knew what was wrong, so people suggested I add the rest of the code. I suggest you use your eyes next time, might help you look like less of an ass.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because of trailing newline character. So, before you actually do `if($ret != 'y')` just trim it `$ret = trim($ret)`. give it a try.

```
$ret = $_GET['r'];
$ret = trim($ret);
if ($ret!='y') 
 {
   // rest of your code
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
<?php
    $ret = $_GET['r'];
    if($ret != "y") {
        echo "Yay!";
    } else {
        echo ":(";
    }
?>
<html>
    <head>

    </head>

    <body>
        <form method="get" action="search.php">
             <input type="checkbox" value="y" name="r" />Submit Query<br />
             <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" />
        </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: it printed out yay when it was selected, and :( when it wasn't

Comment: it worked without the edit, and stopped working with it. maybe its the "!" thats causing all the trouble?

Comment: Thats weird. I guess you could try if(strcmp($ret, "y"))